# unexpected result in mef

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, mef

i am beginner in MEF. i write this code but i cant understand why program show this result.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class MEFTest
    {
         [Import]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [Import]
        public IExtension Ext { get; set; }

        public void ShowText()
        {
            AssemblyCatalog asscatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Extension2).Assembly);
            CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(asscatalog);

            CompositionBatch batch = new CompositionBatch();
            batch.AddPart(this);

            container.Compose(batch);

            Console.WriteLine(Text);
            Console.WriteLine(Ext.Text);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            MEFTest mef = new MEFTest();

            mef.ShowText();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public interface IExtension
    {
        string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [Export]
    public class Extension1 : IExtension
    {
        [Export]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public Extension1()
        {
            Text = "From Extension1.";
        }
    }

    [Export(typeof(IExtension))]
    public class Extension2 : IExtension
    {
       // [Export(typeof(IExtension).GetProperties()[0].GetType())]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public Extension2()
        {
            Text = "From Extension2.";
        }
    }
}
```

result :

From Extension1.
From Extension2.

Comment: Is your result Form Extenstion1. Form Extension2?

Comment: Hazai, as Reed stated below, you must remove the [Import] public string Text {get;set;} you don't need this.

Answer (score 2):

This is just how MEF is matching your imports.  Since you have:

```
    [Import]
    public string Text { get; set; }
```

In this case, MEF finds a "string Text" and does the match.  This happens from Extention1, but *only because you explicitly added an export to its Text property*.

```
    [Import]
    public IExtension Ext { get; set; }
```

This finds the actual `Export` of type `IExtension`.  The only one of these is your `Extension2` class.  This fulfills this requirement.

Comment: I think he's saying that both Form Extension 1 and Form Extension 2 are being shown.

Comment: @Jethro: Yes, but he has 2 separate imports, and is printing both.  As I said above, teh first import finds Extension1, the second finds Extension2.

Comment: I see, so what happening is that the Import is if matching the Extension1 Text property. Thanks.

Comment: @Jethro: Yes.  If you export the Text property from Extension2, as well, you'll get an exception, since there will be more than 1 matching import...

Answer (score 0):

Extension1 declares that it exports itself (type Extension1, not the interface) and exports a property named Text of type string.

In composition, this will be bound to the Text property tagged as import.

Extension2 declares that it exports type IExtension.  This will be bound to the Ext property tagged to import IExtension.